# Swing & JavaFX: how to convert JavaFX MouseEvent to Swing MouseEvent?

Tags: java, swing, javafx, mouseevent

The package `SwingUtilities` has a nice function, `convertMouseEvent`, to convert a mouse event on a component to a mouse event on another component:

```java
MouseEvent convertedEvent = SwingUtilities.convertMouseEvent(originalComponent, event, otherComponent);
```

Meanwhile, the `MouseEvent` in JavaFX has a method `copyFor` to create a copy of the `MouseEvent` for another component:

```java
MouseEvent convertedEvent = e.copyFor(e.getSource(), otherComponent);
```

I would like to do something similar to convert a JavaFx MouseEvent `e` to a Swing mouse event.

I couldn't find a baked in function, so I tried to write my own. There are two fields I can't readily convert though:

- Id field that identifies the event. I assume I'll have to manually convert from `e.getEventType().getEventType().getName()`
- In JavaFX there is no "when" property indicating when the event occurred. It seems I could use the current system time here
- The modifier of the mouse event. I'm not sure how to build those from the properties of the JavaFX event

Is there a way to get the modifier from the properties of `e`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functions in `SwingEvents` can be useful. They can be accessed with the import

`import com.sun.javafx.embed.swing.SwingEvents;`

**To convert from JavaFX to Swing:**

`SwingEvents.fxMouseButtonToMouseButton(fxEvent)`: converts a JavaFX event to a Swing mouse button.

`SwingEvents.fxMouseEventTypeToMouseID(fxEvent)`: converts a JavaFX event to a Swing mouse ID.

`SwingEvents.fxMouseModsToMouseMods(fxEvent)`: converts a JavaFX event to Swing mods.

**To convert from Swing to JavaFX:**

`SwingEvents.mouseIDToEmbedMouseType(swingEvent.getID())`: converts a Swing mouse event ID to a JavaFX MouseType.

`SwingEvents.mouseButtonToEmbedMouseButton(swingEvent.getButton, swingEvent.getModifiersEx())`: converts a Swing mouse button to a JavaFX mouse button. Currently bugged (JDK-8242419).